# Execute script after template render in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I need to call

```
jQuery('#nav').spasticNav();
```

for activating spasticNav animation on my menu; the menu (#nav) is included in the Ember App main template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
...
<div id="nav">...</div>
...
</script>
```

Before using Ember i was calling spasticNav just before `</body>` tag, but now i have to wait the template is fully rendered before; how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that needs to be executed after the view has been rendered into the DOM can be done in the `didInsertElement` hook of a view.

For example if your view is called `index` then define a view:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    jQuery('#nav').spasticNav();
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So we need to render the page as a view, not automatically as a template? I hope you understand the question.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, this question was do my lack of understanding of Ember. I figured it out.